# How to prompt user to sign in after filling out form while keeping form data with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a Rails 4 App an Order Model where a user fills out a form for necessary data for price calculations etc. What I want is that they are prompted to sign in (with DEVISE gem) at the end of step_3 and are routed to a payment section but they can store their form data from the Order Model that the user has previously filled out, this data being the order form data before they signed in.

Main Issues:

1. Redirecting them after sign in mid way through process using devise
2. Saving the form data and associating it with the current user immediately before routed to the payment section
3. the Order.find_by section. What do I find the order by?

Background:
Rails 4 
PostgreSQL
Devise Gem

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:step_1,:process_step1,:step_2a,:process_step_2a, :step_2b, :step_2c, :step_3]

def step_1
  @order = Order.find_by id: session[:order_id]
  if @order.nil?
  @order=Order.new
  @order.save!
  end
end

def process_step1
order = Order.find_by id: session[:order_id]   
order.update_attributes(order_params)
if (order.building == 'Residential') || (order.building == 'Commercial' )
  redirect_to step_2a_path
elsif (order.building == 'Commercial + Parking') || (order.building == 'Residential + Parking')
  redirect_to step_2b_path
else
  redirect_to step_2c_path
  end
end

  def step_2a
   @order = Order.find_by id: params[:session_id]
 end

  def process_step_2a
  order= Order.find_by status: 'cart'
# , user_id: current_user.id
order.update_attributes(order_params)
if order.save
  redirect_to step_3_path
  end
  end

  def step_2b
  @order= Order.find_by status:'cart'
# , user_id: current_user.id
  end

  def process_step_2b
  order= Order.find_by status: 'cart'
# , user_id: current_user.id
order.update_attributes(order_params)
if order.save
  redirect_to step_3_path
end
 end

  def step_2c
  @order= Order.find_by status:'cart'
  # , user_id: current_user.id
  end

  def process_step_2c
   order= Order.find_by status: 'cart'
   order.update_attributes(order_params)
    if order.save
  redirect_to step_3_path
end
  end

  def step_3
  @order= Order.find_by status:'cart'
# , user_id: current_user.id
  end

 def process_step_3
   order= Order.find_by status: 'cart', user_id: current_user.id
   order.update_attributes(order_params)
   if order.save
  redirect_to payment_path
end
 end

 def payment
  @order= Order.find_by status:'cart', user_id: current_user.id
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you should really refactor you routes. With that structure your application is going to get exponentially more confusing to navigate the larger it grows, and will make it practically impossible for anyone else to work on it/help you with debugging. Take a look at this guide on [RESTful routing](https://richonrails.com/articles/understanding-rails-routing) to learn more.

As for you issue, you can store their form data in one of the rails temporary storage mechanisms (I'd recommend a [session variable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions)) while they're logging in then redisplay it after they finish

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a callback after_sign_in_path_for, you can add it in your ApplicationController. Usage is [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

2,3. Continue to use session[:order_id]. Can't figure out why do you use find_by status: 'cart' and Order.find_by id: params[:session_id]. Check [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3706) url to save old session after log in.

Personally I do not recommend this method and I think it's better to bind order id to some secure random generated value stored in cookie.